# How to convert a wget request to a http request

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest

I use:

> wget --no-check-certificate --http-user=user --http-password=secret --header="Content-Type:text/xml" --post-file=request.xml  https://mydominain.com/xml

to send an xml request.

The xml file (request.xml) is something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request method="switchvox.call">
<parameters>
<dial_first>1111</dial_first>
<dial_second>2222</dial_second>
<dial_as_account_id>1127</dial_as_account_id>
<caller_id_name>John Doe</caller_id_name>
</parameters>
</request>
```

I need to test some xml requests before write a program.

It is posible to send the same request using a browser? 
Is it posible use copy-paste in a browser to test the request? 
Is it possible to send a xml file in a browser request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is posible to send the same request using a browser?

Since you are using a non-standard (for browser forms) content-type in your request: Only by using JavaScript with XMLHttpRequest.

> Is it posible use copy-paste in a browser to test the request?

No … well you could write the script and then copy and paste it into the JS console.

> Is it possible to send a xml file in a browser request?

Given the provisos above, yes, but it seems to be rather more trouble then your existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of with a browser but you can use Fiddler to create raw http requests with any content you like.

You can also capture the http requests when browsing to sites if you want/need to recreate them.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/